# I can't get my script to add a attachment to send email through PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to add an attachment to the email that PowerShell is sending but I can't get it to work.

I tried to set the attachment location as a variable but no luck.

```
$EmailFrom = “Whatever@domain.com”
$EmailToAddresses = @(“email1”,"email2")
$Subject = “Your choice!”
$attachment = "C:\Users\simeo\Desktop\WebTest\Website_log.txt"
$Body = “The website is unreachable”
$SMTPServer = “smtp”
foreach ($EmailTo in $EmailToAddresses) {
    $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $attachment, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body) 
}
```

I just want to send email to more than one recipient with a log file attachment.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also have a look at Send-MailMessage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6

Comment: The [`SMTPClient.Send()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send) method has 2 overloads: one that accepts a single `MailMessage` parameter, and one that accepts 4 String parameters (sender address, recipient address(es), subject, and message body). For sending a mail with an attachment you need the former.

Comment: There is just this error when i try to add $attachment " Cannot find an overload for "Send" and the argument count: "5".
"

Comment: Please re-read my previous comment. `Send()` has an overload with 1 parameter. `Send()` has an overload with 4 parameters. `Send()` does not have an overload with 5 parameters. What gave you the idea that it would?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way. it works fine when i'm using it.

```
$EmailFrom = “Whatever@domain.com”
$EmailToAddresses = @(“email1”,"email2")
$Subject = “test!”
$attachment = "C:\files\file1.txt"
$Body = “test”
$SMTPServer = “Mail.smtp.com”
foreach ($EmailTo in $EmailToAddresses)
{

    Send-MailMessage -To $EmailTo -From $EmailFrom -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -Attachments $attachment -SmtpServer $SMTPServer

}
```

As stated in a comment above.

SmtpClient.Send Method has

```
Send(String sender, String receiver, String subject, String body)
```

Comment: This one works but im only able to send emails within our company and not outside email clients like gmail or yahoo, and i need it to be able to send to gmail as well

Comment: @Smiley, Then it has to do with the SMTP relay, i think. I just send 2 mails, one to my private hotmail and one to my business mail.

Comment: Oky so should my code then look like this ------>   https://www.codepile.net/pile/AmJvJ4m0

Comment: I just tried it like above but it was only delivered to my organization and not to my gmail but when is use this code ----------> https://www.codepile.net/pile/1ZvR42Ze
its delivered to both gmail and business email but i cant get to attach a log file